# Can ListViewItem style property be reset from ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can something like this be done through attributes or templates (pseudo xaml :))

```
<ListView ListViewItem.Style={x:Null}>
</ListView>
```

This question is not just about ListView, it's about all ItemsControl's classes, is there a way to set or reset style for item's from container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{x:Null}"/>
```

Works for any ItemsControl:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tried this before, somehow it doesn't work. I am using WPF theme from codeplex, and it defines Style with ListViewItem as TargetType. If I insert in ListView something like this <ListViewItem Style="{x:Null}">...</ListViewItem> style ll be reseted (also i can reset style from code, but it doesn't feel right). I don't know why this happening, maybe i don't understand something about how styles work :(

Comment: Thank's for the tip again :) Really strange behavior:
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{x:Null}"/> won't work, value mustn't be null, so:
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style></Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
Works just fine.